# Using arcoreimg from command line

Tags: android, macos, command-line, terminal, arcore

I need to evaluate the image quality of several images using the arcoreimg tool to process a failed build in Unreal using blueprints.

I'm running on a Mac, but far more familiar with a PC. I've tried the following:

```
./arcoreimg eval-img --input_image_path=/Users/scull/Documents/Proj/Content/images/s_recog_turl.png
```

- No such file or directory

I have located the *ptdbtool_macos_lipobin* tool in the ~Library and tried running it from there but to no avail:

```
/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.21/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/GoogleARCore/Binaries/ThirdParty/Google/ARCoreImg/Mac
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To my future self:

Use

```
./ptdbtool_macos_lipobin eval-img --input_image_path=/Users/scull/Documents/Proj/Content/images/s_recog_turl.png
```

Looks like someone at [Android](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg) forgot to rename the executable to *arcoreimg*.